# How do I obtain an accurate measure of latency/ping?

Tags: networking, windows, statistics, latency

I'm writing some C++ on a Windows system to extract latency from Win32 API so that I can make a ubiquitous ping/latency overlay for windows/DX apps, but the values I receive from Windows do not correlate with in-game performance.

Could someone please explain what's going on and how I can obtain values that have a direct correlation with those found in-game? i.e. high in-game ping should be able to be detected via Windows Win32 API in near realtime.

In the example, I've loaded up:

1. Resource monitor - the gameserver is 50.16.132.167
2. GW2 (DirectX) - bottom right of the ingame options menu
3. an MSI Afterburner overlay - displayed ontop of the minimap

The MSI Afterburner overlay using Win32 API is calling GetPerTcpConnectionEStats (iphlpapi.h) to get [TCP_ESTATS_PATH_ROD_v0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tcpestats/ns-tcpestats-tcp_estats_path_rod_v0). SampleRtt is being used in the example.

[image: GW2 latency (ping) measurement comparisons]